# I have a question about writing loops in R

Tags: r

I have two databases, one includes 2283 rows of products information (USDA) and the second one is 621 flavor type of products (Flavor). I wanted to use grepl code to recognize the flavor in each row of my first dataset. However, I do not want to write the code for each flavor one by one. Therefore, I decided to write a loop. However, my loop is not showing multiple columns of results for each flavor check. Instead, it is showing the result of the last match. Would you please help me with this problem?

for (i in 2:length(Flavor$Flavor_names){

```
              result <-  cbind(USDA, Flavor=grepl(paste0(Flavor_names$FLAVOR.SCENT[i], collapse="|") , USDA$long_name)))
```

Comment: Hey could you post some of the data?

Answer (score 0):

Before starting a loop like this, you need to create an empty object to fill up with all the results of the loop. Such as `result <- NULL`. Second, when you run the loop, index the output object as you do the input objects, like `result[i]`. Your loop would look like:

```
result <- NULL

for (i in 2:length(Flavor$Flavor_names){
result[i] <-  cbind(USDA, Flavor=grepl(paste0(Flavor_names$FLAVOR.SCENT[i], collapse="|") , USDA$long_name)))
}
```

Now `results` is length i, and in positions `2` through `length(Flavor$Flavor_names)` you have the results of the `i-th` loop. Note that index `1` will be `NA`, because you started your loop with `2`. You could avoid this if your loop had contained `result[i - 1]` instead.